# "Looks daggers" vs. "look daggers"

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality

"Looks daggers" or "look daggers": which one is correct?

[Ngram results here](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=looks%20daggers,look%20daggers&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) show almost equal results but when I searched for [*He looks daggers* or *He look daggers*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he%20looks%20dagger,he%20look%20dagger&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), I didn't find any matches.

For example:

> 1) John look daggers at Mike.
>
> 2) John looks daggers at Mike.

I'm not sure whether the first example is grammatically correct or it should be written like the second example, and the Ngram doesn't show any matches.

Comment: *John **look** daggers at Mike* is just plain wrong. The verb *to look* is perfectly regular, as are the vast majority of English words. *I look, you look, she looks, **John looks***. But as Mari-Lou A says, you wouldn't normally use *to look **daggers*** in Simple Present anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is more common to use either the past or the present continuous tense, as testified by these online dictionaries:

- http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/look+daggers+at
- http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/look+daggers

> Tom must have been mad at Ann from the way he was looking daggers at her.

> I could see my partner looking daggers at me.

And here are the results at [Ngram Viewer](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=looking+daggers+at%2Clooked+daggers+at%2Clooks+daggers+at&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) comparing "Looking daggers at", "Looked daggers at" and "Looks daggers at" The third person present simple is tiny in comparison:

[image]

Comment: Additionally, *glaring daggers* is much more idiomatic than *looking daggers*.

Comment: @WendiKidd♦: It [just makes it onto the radar](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=glared+daggers%2Clooked+daggers&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) over the last 20-30 years, but I don't see *glare* overtaking *look* any time soon.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Huh, interesting! I'd honestly never heard *looking daggers* before I came across this question, I'd only heard *glaring*. Funny what common things aren't common in some places!

Comment: @WendiKidd I was going to ask if "glaring" was British, since I had never heard it, and I mean not once. But I see you're from Dallas. So, hmm.

Comment: @WendiKidd: I think both variations are seriously "dated". I can imagine my mother saying *someone [was looking daggers](http://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22was+looking+daggers%22&tbs=qdr:y&ei=fkWrUaLUKqmu0QX8-4GIDQ&start=40&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47244034,d.d2k&fp=a525e40f95575556&biw=1292&bih=916) at someone else*. But she's well into her 80s. Google shows only 47 hits for that on the whole Internet in the past year. It's also a bit "literary" (almost [7000 instances](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22was+looking+daggers%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) in Google **Books**).